# Pandas reset_index() - change default to drop index

Tags: python, pandas

I've been using Python and Pandas for years and know it well, but I use the `reset_index()` feature a lot and I'd say 95% of the time, also use `drop = True` as a keyword.  If I'm resetting the index, I think it's a good bet that I don't want to keep the old index in my dataframe.  Is there a way to set `drop = True` as the default, and if I don't want to drop it, instead use `drop = False`?

I looked at the `pd.set_option()` documentation and didn't see what I was looking for.

Comment: Changing the source code? `pandas/core/frame.py` and `pandas/core/series.py`; finding the `reset_index` method in there and changing default value of keyword argument `drop`.

Comment: That might be the only way.  I know there are some options you can change that don't require changing the source code, thus the question.  But thanks for the paths, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new `reset_index` method:

```
pd.DataFrame.my_reset_index = lambda self: self.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.my_reset_index()
```

Comment: Interesting, and that could be done directly within the module?  No need to mess with the source code?  I don't love that I'd have to update literally hundreds of `reset_index()` in my code, but that's definitely an option.